# Show response from server on web page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am developing a web app using HTML, PHP and JavaScript. I found a way to call PHP methods that run database operations from the client-side (HTML and JS) using AJAX, here's an example:

```
    if (confirm('Sure you want to do that?')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "myScripts.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          paramForOperation: myParam,
          option: "doAction1"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          //Here I reload or load another page after server is done
          window.open("myPage.php", "_self");
        }
      });
    }
```

So here I call the php file with the script that does an INSERT/ DELETE / WHATEVER on the database. It works fine, but what if I couldn't insert because the index already exists or any other reason? What if some type of data is wrong and I can't insert it? I know I can validate that on the server side using PHP, but how do I return a message saying "Operation complete" or "You should use numbers on X field"?

I thought of something like `alert(response);` but what will it return? An `echo($msg);` from my PHP functions? Is there a way to send the result message on that `response` thing in AJAX?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should read about HTTP Response Codes ( 200 OK, 204 No Content, 400 Error , 404 Not Found). In the response, you can get the http code that your API returned. If it is in 4XX family, it's an error. And you need to defined the `fail:  function(err) { }` callback

Answer (score 0):

Any output of the PHP script will be received in response. Remember, the PHP script runs on the server and just generates output. The PHP code itself never reaches the client.

So, you can just echo a message, and alert it in Response.

Bringing it up a notch, you can return [a small piece of JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or XML that can be parsed and which can contain an error message and some error code, so you script can also respond to that, and maybe change its behaviour (if the insert succeeded, add the new data to the page, for instance).

And of course, instead of returning always code 200 (meaning OKAY) from PHP, you could consider [returning other HTTP status codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php), so the code already indicates whether something went wrong or not. Depending on the status code, jQuery will execute either the success or the error handler, so it's easy to make different handlers for different situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let your server respond with appropriate HTTP Status Codes and meaningful error messages. Use the error function of the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myScripts.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    success: function(response) {
      /* no error occured, do stuff... */
    }
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      /* handle the error, add custom error messages to any DOM objects, ... */
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

Some docs: [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)